# Decompress data on the fly from offsets in the original data?

Tags: compression

I have a block of data I want to compress, say, C structures of variable sizes. I want to compress the data, but access specific fields of structures on the fly in application code without having to decompress the entire data.

Is there an algorithm which can take the offset (for the original data), decompress and return the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression methods generally achieve compression by making use of the preceding data. At any point in the compressed data, you need to know at least some amount of the preceding uncompressed data in order to decompress what follows.

You can deliberately forget the history at select points in the compressed data in order to have random access at those points. This reduces the compression by some amount, but that can be small with sufficiently distant random access points. A simple approach would be to compress pieces with gzip and concatenate the gzip streams, keeping a record of the offsets of each stream. For less overhead, you can use `Z_FULL_FLUSH` in zlib to do the same thing.

Alternatively, you can save the history at each random access point in a separate file. An example of building such a random access index to a zlib or gzip stream can be found in [zran.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zran.c).

You can construct compression methods that do not depend on previous history for decompression, such as simple Huffman coding. However the compression ratio will be poor compared to methods that do depend on previous history.

Comment: Thanks. Could I also write back to the compressed data?

Comment: Not really, no, since you can't predict the size of the compressed data.

Answer (score 0):

Example compressed file system: There we have a filesystem API which doesn't need to know about the compression that happens before it's written to disk. There are a few algorithms out there.
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561664/where-can-i-find-a-lossless-compression-algorithm-which-produces-headerless-out) for more details.

However, maybe there is more gain in trying to optimize the used data structures so there is no need to compress them?
For efficient access an index is needed. So between arrays and MultiMaps and Sparse Arrays there should be a way to model the data that there is no need for further compression as the data is represented efficiently.
Of course this depends largely on the use case which is quite ambiguous.

A use case where a compression layer is needed to access the data is possible to imagine, but it's likely that there are better ways to solve the problem.